# How to setup routes for multidimensional requests?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I wasnt sure what to call the title, but I guessed. :P

Basically I wanted to setup a somewhat complicated website, and I dont know how to setup the routes. Here is how it would work.

`/ruby` would show info on Ruby programming language

`/ruby/rails` would show info on ROR

`/ruby/sinatra` would show info on sinatra

`/php` would show info on PHP

`/php/laravel` would show info on Laravel

ETC.

Im not sure exactly how everything would work. I want a controller for each framework/language. I am thinking to making a folder for each language and having controller in it, but im not really sure if thats the best option.

**EDIT**: I forgot to mention that each langugae will have its own set of pages. EX.

`/ruby/rails/models` shows info on rails models

`/ruby/rails/controllers` shows info on rails controllers

`/ruby/rails/routing` shows info on rails routing

`/ruby/oop` talks about oop

`/ruby/variables` shows how to define variables

ETC. **Its essentially going to be sort of like documentation**.

Thanks!

Comment: What content are you suppose to populate for each language? Static or dynamic? If dynamic, what your models?

Comment: @JaugarChang It is all static. I just updated my post. It would be great if you could read the edits! Thanks! :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Beginner with Rails 3.1 and "static" pages](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7350334/beginner-with-rails-3-1-and-static-pages)

Comment: @JaugarChang Im not really sure how this is a duplicate...

Comment: The routes.rb file is not involved with serving static assets. You can move your resources to projects /public directory. Ensure all the pages named `index.html` with the directory structure posted in your question.

Comment: By static I didnt refer to that. I meant that most of the pages are typed out. There will still be some dynamic parts to it. I could put them in the public pages, but I dont not want to.

Comment: Still unclear what you meant. Can you make some example of the `dynamic parts`?

Comment: Ads, Unique Comment System, Edit parts of pages (NOT the Title).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html Section 3.2, "Dynamic Segments"

```
get ':controller/:action'
```

Now create a controller for each language. For example, php.rb, ruby.rb, etc. Each framework is an action in that controller

```
class Ruby < ApplicationController
    def rails
    end
    def sinatra
    end
end
```

**EDIT**

I don't have the time to test this one at the moment, but let me know if it works or not :-)

```
# Routes.rb:

get ':controller/:action/:pagename'
```

And then for the Ruby class

```
class Ruby < ApplicationController
    def rails
        if template_exists?("#{params[:pagename]}", _prefixes)
            render params[:pagename]
        end
    end
end
```

Comment: Hey! Thanks for the reply. I forgot to add a key part to the question. I just edited the post. It would be great if you could read that and edit your post! Thanks! :)

Comment: Edited, but not tested. Let me know if this works :-)